Issue with \ekvcSecondaryKeys: why my usage cause errors?
I meet a strange issue when using \ekvcSecondaryKeys.
Here is my MWE:
\ekvcSplit\NewTheorem{%
  name=,%#1
  numberlike=,%#2
  display=,%#3
  numberin=,%#4
  refname=,%#5
  Refname=,%#6
  style=,%#7
}{%
  \IfBlankF{#7}{
    \theoremstyle{#7}
  }% theorem style
  \IfBlankTF{#2}{
    \IfBlankTF{#4}{
      \newtheorem{#1}{#3}
    }{
      \newtheorem{#1}{#3}[#4]
    }
  }{
    \newtheorem{#1}[#2]{#3}
  }% newtheorem
}
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\NewTheorem{%
  meta name = { display = #1 },
}
\NewTheorem{name=ABC,numberin=section}

If I delete the \ekvcSecondaryKeys part, it works. However, with the \ekvcSecondaryKeys part, I get endless mistakes.
Here is the messages:
LaTeX Warning: Command `\the' already defined -- not changed on input
line 86.

./test.tex:86: Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again> 
                   \thm@style  l.86 \NewTheorem{name=ABC,numberin=section}
                                            ./test.tex:89: Argument of \rem@pt has an extra }. <inserted text> 
                \par  l.89 \begin{document}
                      Runaway argument? \arabic {}\@tempdimb  ./test.tex:89: Paragraph ended before \rem@pt was complete. <to be
read again> 
                   \par  l.89 \begin{document}
                      ./test.tex:89: Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again> 
                   \scan_stop:  l.89 \begin{document}
                      ./test.tex:89: Extra \endcsname. \font@name .../ \scan_stop: \tex_par:D \endcsname 
                                                   l.89 \begin{document}
                      ./test.tex:89: Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> 
                   scan_stop:  l.89 \begin{document}
                      ./test.tex:89: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). <to be read again> 
                   scan_stop:  l.89 \begin{document}
                      ./test.tex:89: Missing = inserted for ifdim. <to be read again> 
                   scan_stop:  l.89 \begin{document}
                      ./test.tex:89: Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> 
                   scan_stop:  l.89 \begin{document}
                      ./test.tex:89: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). <to be read again> 
                   scan_stop:  l.89 \begin{document}
                      ./test.tex:89: Extra endcsname. f@size ->scan_stop: tex_par:D endcsname 
                                         l.89 \begin{document}
                      ./test.tex:89: Missing { inserted. <to be read again> 
                   5 l.89 \begin{document}
                      ) Runaway text? 5p@ set@simple@size@args <6><7><8><9><10><12>gen*cmr<10.95>cmr10<14.4ETC. ! File ended while
scanning text of toks. <inserted text> 
                } <*> test
         ! Emergency stop. <*> test

Can anyone give me a help?

please provide a complete minimal example we can use to reproduce the error. those are not standard commands. how are you defining them? and please format code with the {} button rather than formatting it as a quote.

Do you think this isn't clear enough from the documentation? If so, do you want to suggest better wording to make it abundantly clear that \ekvcSecondaryKeys will overwrite any existing definition of a key?

With \ekvcSecondaryKeys you define new keys, by doing meta name = { display = #1 } you're removing the definition of name as a primary key, hence your #1 in the replacement text of \NewTheorem is empty and you end up doing \newtheorem{}{ABC}[section] and that errors.
What you rather want is a key that sets both the primary key of #1 (you called it name) and the display key. To achieve this while still using name as the frontend key you can change the primary key to name-internal and define a secondary key name that sets both keys.
Something like the following:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\ekvcSplit\NewTheorem{%
  name-internal=,%#1
  numberlike=,%#2
  display=,%#3
  numberin=,%#4
  refname=,%#5
  Refname=,%#6
  style=,%#7
}{%
  \IfBlankF{#7}{%
    \theoremstyle{#7}%
  }% theorem style
  \IfBlankTF{#2}{%
    \IfBlankTF{#4}{%
      \newtheorem{#1}{#3}%
    }{%
      \newtheorem{#1}{#3}[#4]%
    }%
  }{%
    \newtheorem{#1}[#2]{#3}%
  }% newtheorem
}
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\NewTheorem{
  meta name = { display = {#1}, name-internal = {#1} },
}
\NewTheorem{name=ABC,numberin=section}

\begin{document}
\begin{ABC}
  This is ABC.
\end{ABC}
\end{document}

